# Simulink .NET integration

Tags: .net, matlab, simulink, osisoft

I am working on a project where I need to integrate a certain PI-AF (database) with a Simulink model. I know that PI-AF has a certain .NET AF-SDK api through which I can reference/access the elements/attributes. And I also know that you can load a .NET assembly into MATLAB and use the .NET libraries. However, can we do the same in Simulink ? I know you can create a function block in Simulink where you can write MATLAB functions that would be executed with the given inputs and also return a certain value. Is it possible to load a .NET assembly in this function block? I am completely new to Simulink and MATLAB and have never really worked on them before. It would be great if one of you guys can share your knowledge on the above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what sort of integration you are after:

If you just want to load some data from the database, run your Simulink model using that data, and then maybe write some data back onto the database once the simulation is finished, you don't need to the MATLAB Function block you refer to. Simply write your MATLAB code (as scripts or functions, doesn't matter), and call those scripts/functions in the [model callbacks](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/model-callbacks.html): probably in the `PreLoadFcn`, `PostLoadFcn` or `InitFcn` callback for the code to load the data from the database, and in the `StopFcn` for the code to write the data back to the database.

If, on the other hand, you want to continually interact with the database as the simulation progresses, then it's more complicated and you do need to use the [MATLAB Function](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block, as you suggested. That block uses (C) code generation under the hood, which I suspect the .NET related functions won't support, so you'll have to define them as `extrinsic` (see [Call MATLAB Functions](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/calling-matlab-functions.html) in the documentation for more details). Be aware though that functions declared as extrinsic return outputs of type `mxArray`, which need to be converted to a known type before they can be used by other functions/statements/etc... How to do this is explained in the aforementioned documentation page.

Comment: Great. So i do not need to interact continually with the database during the simulation. I only need to load some data from the database and write back to the database after the model executes. But in the first scenario that you mentioned, can i load .net assemblies into the MATLAB code? In short, can i do everything that I can do when coding in MATLAB? I would prefer to write it as a script, can i call that script?

Comment: I don't know anything about .NET but anything you can do in MATLAB you can put in your script, and yes it can be a script.

Comment: Thanks a lot. All i need to do is load an assembly and my work is sorted. From your comment it seems very possible. Thank you. Do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Since the workflow is (1) load from db, (2) simulate model, (3) write to db, then it might be more straightforward to avoid using the model callbacks to execute steps (1) and (3).  Consider that you can use the [sim command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/sim.html) in MATLAB to simulate your Simulink model and get the output (step 2).  So, you could just write one MATLAB script that handles all 3 steps.  Basically, it's just a question of whether you want to drive your workflow with your Simulink model (original suggestion) or drive it with a MATLAB script (my suggestion).

Comment: @grungetta good suggestion. I personally prefer driving from Simulink, even if the callback is a simple call to a more complicated script. I guess it's a matter of preference. I only use 'sim' when in a for loop or when I need a high level of automation.

Comment: @am304 I agree. It mostly just comes down to personal preference and the particular use case -- specifically, how does Simulink fit into your workflow.  I find myself doing a fair bit of automation, so I probably tend to lean more towards driving from MATLAB.  But, yeah... if the Simulink simulation is really the focus here and loading/writing to the db are minor setup/teardown operations bookending the process, then you're probably right that driving from Simulink might make more sense.